# Create new directory in Gitlab WebIDE

Tags: github, gitlab

I am using GITLabs WebIDE to add/edit and checkin new files to by project.

When I select **New Directory** like so I can see my new folder created:

[image]

But it does not allow me to commit the added folder as the Commit button does not become highlighted:

[image]

How can I create a new directory via GitLab WebIDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a file to the newly created directory, then you will be allowed to stage and commit a change.